# How to install SDKMAN on FreeBSD 12 RELEASE?

Tags: freebsd, sdkman

I'm trying to install SDKMAN package manager on a FreeBSD machine.
I successfully executed:

`curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash`

The problem occurs when I am trying to run:

`source "/root/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"`

I got the following error in the terminal:

`Illegal variable name.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FreeBSD doesn't have `bash` by default, so you're probably running different shell. Try running `bash` first to enter bash prompt and then run that `source ...` command.